# TypeError: cannot serialize '_io.TextIOWrapper' object- Flask

Tags: flask, redis, task-queue, python-rq

I am writing a flask app that asks user to upload excel spreadsheet and then calculate and populate the database.I am trying to do the processing part in the background via **Redis RQ** but I keep getting *TypeError: cannot serialize '_io.TextIOWrapper' object*
my code looks like this:

```
from redis import Redis
from rq import Queue
from rq.job import Job
import xlrd as x

workbook = x.open_workbook('data.xls')
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
q = Queue(connection = Redis())

def populate(sheet,row,column):
    #extract data and save into database

job = enqueue_call(func=populate, args=(sheet,7,5), result_ttl = 5000)
print(job.get_id())
```